# Unintentionally turned my array into a scalar?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I am a python beginner and I am looking to create an array of 1's and -1's. I began with an NxN matrix of values ranging from 0 to 1, then converted this into 1's and -1's with np.where. Or so I thought. When trying to access this array later in the code I'm getting the error message.

> return 2 * array1[x, y] * sum((array1, N, x, y))
>
> "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable"

```
def randomarray(N):
    array1 = np.random.rand(N,N)
    array1 = np.where(array1 <= 0.5, 1,-1)
    return array1

def closepoints(array1, N, x, y):
    return array1[(x - 1) % N, y] + array1[(x + 1) % N, y] + \
    array1[x, (y - 1) % N] + array1[x, (y + 1) % N]

def flip(array1, N, x ,y):
    return 2 * array1[x, y] * sum(closepoints(array1, N, x, y)) ***line where error is occuring***
sweeps_no = 50
lat = randomarray(N)

for k in range(sweeps_no):
       
    i = np.random.randint(N) #randomly selecting an individual lattice point
    j = np.random.randint(N)
    
    array1 = closepoint(lat, N, i, j)
    energy = flip(lat[i,j], array1, i, j)
    print energy
    if energy <= 0:
        lat[i,j] *= -lat[i,j]
        energies += energy
        energycount.append(energies)
```

I'm pretty sure this is because of the line:

```
array1 = np.where(array1 <= 0.5, 1,-1)
```

That array1 is just any given point rather than an actual array?
What's confusing me is that I'm not getting the error message for the function closepoints which is first, only flip. I tried printing array1 and got -4 back so its definitely a scalar. I can't figure out how to word my randomarray function so that it returns an actual array, and not just points of the array.

Comment: It would help to understand how you call `flip`. Also, I think this error is because you call `sum`, a python function, on a numpy array. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Will edit my question to include that code now.  Well I am trying to calculate the energy change resulting from flipping a spin of a given point on the matrix. The calculation for this energy change requires summing the adjacent points.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no, the error happens before that (indexing `array1[x, y]` when `array1` is a scalar).

Comment: `array1 = np.where(array1 <= 0.5, 1, -1)` is fine. The issue is `energy = flip(lat[i,j], array1, i, j)`. `flip()` needs an array as the first argument, you're passing in a single value `lat[i, j]`. Not sure what you're trying to do here tbh.

Answer (score 2):

`lat[i, j]` is a scalar right? You can't do `lat[i, j][x, y]`

Comment: even before lat[i,j] I am recieving an error when trying to call the function flip, but I can't figure out why array1 is a scalar

Comment: Try to add keyword arguments to make it clear to yourself what you are doing
`energy = flip(array1=lat[i,j], N=array1, x=i, y=j)`
is this what you want?